# SQL Query check if ID is part of another table

Tags: sql, select, subquery, left-join, innodb

I have 2 tables:

tblBook:
BookID, Title

tblFavorite:
FavoriteID, UserID, BookID

I would like to develop a SQL query to Select BookID, Title, IsFavorite (true|false) while given the UserID as parameter.

Foreach BookID there should be checked if there is a row with this BookID and the given UserID in tblFavorite. -> true/false

Comment: How do you convert FavoriteID to True/False?

Comment: That's the question. When there is a row with this BookID and the given UserID in tblFavorite, the value of IsFavorite should be true, otherwise false.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
select b.*, 
    case when exists (select 1 from tblfavorite f where f.bookid = b.bookid and f.userid = ?)
        then 1
        else 0
    end as isfavorite
from tblbook b
```

The question mark represents the id of the user for who you are generating the report. In databases that support evaluating conditions as booleans or integers (such as MySQL or Postgres for example), you can dispense the `case` expression:

```
select b.*, 
    exists (select 1 from tblfavorite f where f.bookid = b.bookid and f.userid = ?) as isfavorite
from tblbook b
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a LEFT JOIN and a CASE expression so that if there is no record in tblFavorite (NULL), it shows False, otherwise it's True.

```
SELECT B.BookID, B.Title, CASE WHEN FavoriteID IS NULL THEN 'False' ELSE 'True' END AS IsFavorite
FROM tblBook B
LEFT JOIN tblFavorite F on B.BookID = F.BookID
```